# Azure Synapse integrate, develop options are missing

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Azure Synapse integrate, develop options are missing.

I have created a workspace, when opening in synapse studio and going to integrate menu, it is not giving proper menu options, some options are missing in every menu items.

[image]

Comment: Please check the permissions given to your user in Synapse. Go to manage, access control in synpase workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `Synapse Contributor` for your managed identity in synapse workspace.
Develop tab is present just above Integrate tab. The screenshot you have sent seems as if you are trying to look for develop option within integrate.

[image]